# Logs that are visible on iOS5 are not visible on iOS 6 (only on device)

Tags: ios, logging, ios6

I am using the asl logging framework to log various errors levels and then display them using a method. The error I have is very strange, the method that I use to display the all levels logs works on iOS 5 but in iOS 6 it gives me back only the logs with warning level.

```
-(NSArray*) retrieveLogsWithLevel:(LoggingLevels)level_in forQueryOperation:(QueryOperations)queryOperation
{
[self.accessLock lock];

// subscribe for low memory notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(lowMemoryNotificationReceived:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification 
                                           object:nil];

// build the query
aslmsg aslQuery = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);

const int setQueryStatus1 = asl_set_query(aslQuery, ASL_KEY_SENDER, [self usedByAppName], ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL);



if( (setQueryStatus1 != 0) /*|| (setQueryStatus2 != 0)*/ )
{
    return [NSArray array];
}


// convert enum to string representation
char buff[2];   
sprintf(buff, "%d", level_in);

asl_set_query(aslQuery, ASL_KEY_LEVEL, buff/*"4"*/,
              queryOperation | ASL_QUERY_OP_NUMERIC);

// execute query
aslresponse response = asl_search(NULL, aslQuery);

asl_free( aslQuery );

NSArray* results = [self extractResults:response];

// free the response
aslresponse_free(response); 

// unsubscribe from low memory notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

[self.accessLock unlock];

return results;
}
```

I've tried out the same code on the simulator and it gives back all entries. It is only on a device running on iOS6 that this fails.

Comment: did you have any hint regarding this question?